# In Extjs4.1, how to add additional params before one store sync?

Tags: extjs, store, synchronization, param, operation

In store, there is an event beforeload:

```
beforeload( Ext.data.Store store, Ext.data.Operation operation, Object eOpts )
```

by listening to this event, i can add my additional param to operation when i do query action, like this:

```
store.on('beforeload', function(store, operation) {
    operation.params = Ext.applyIf({
        myParam1: 'param1',
        myParam2: 'param2'
    }, operation.params);
});
```

i also need add my additional params when i do create, update and destroy action. However, the sync event do not pass the operation or store:

```
beforesync( Object options, Object eOpts )
```

is there any other way?

Comment: Are you using autosync? Are the extra params you need to pass dynamic?

Comment: i call store.sync() instead of using autoSync. Does it means i must change extra params every time before i do query or CDU action? @AmitAviv

Comment: Depending on the context of what actually causes the change in the extra params, you may want to use `setExtraParam` when the change occur in the UI. Say there is a checkbox somewhere that is causing the change, you may listen to the change event, and set the extraParam there.

Comment: Or just set it before the sync, write your own sync function, that fetches the extra params, sets them, and do sync.

Answer (score 2):

Use `store.getProxy().setExtraParams({ param: 'value', so:'on' });` hope will work fine :D

Comment: the problem is that the extraParams is only sent on 'read' requests not on create, update, destroy requests if you are defining an API on the store.

Answer (score 1):

Use

> store.getProxy().extraParams.paramName1= paramValue1;
>    store.getProxy().extraParams.paramName2= paramValue2;

Answer (score 0):

ExtraParam will only take effect when call the read api. Not work for create, update, delete

```
grid.store.getProxy().setExtraParam('paramA','XXX');
```

I try another way.

```
grid.store.proxy.api.update = url + "?paramA=XXX"; //set before call sync()
```

Java can get the param by

```
request.getParameter("paramA");
```